# Consistant normal orientation with PCL

Tags: orientation, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, normals

Estimating normals of points in a point cloud using PCL works well, but I get strange normal orientation flip at particular piece of the cloud (see screenshot, normals are yellow lines). Ofcourse I can iterate through the array of normals and correct it, but maybe there is a better way to do it directly with PCL, on the fly? Using viewpoint-oriented normals is not an option because the surface is cylinder-like, so the normals are expected to point in all directions around that axis in the end.

Here is the code for the normal estimation. Basically the snippet from official tutorial:

```
pcl::NormalEstimationOMP<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> n;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr normals(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);
pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree(new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>);
tree->setInputCloud(cloud_);
n.setInputCloud(cloud_);
n.setSearchMethod(tree);
n.setKSearch(10);
n.compute(*normals);
```

[image: Point cloud triangulation with normals]

Comment: Hi Alexander, I am having the same problem, were you able to fix it?

Comment: Hello. Not really. I ended up doing it "manually" with the help of OpenMesh library which I needed for other operations on mesh anyway.

Comment: Ok! I will do the same. Thank you very much

Comment: Can you explain what you did using the openmesh library? Either some pointers in the comments or a self answer if you have a nice algorithm would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code you are looking for can be found in the [Difference of Normals Tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/don_segmentation.php#don-segmentation). Specifically, the lines

```
pcl::NormalEstimationOMP<PointXYZRGB, PointNormal> ne;
...
ne.setViewPoint (std::numeric_limits<float>::max (), 
                 std::numeric_limits<float>::max (), 
                 std::numeric_limits<float>::max ());
...
ne.compute (*normals_large_scale);
```

Where the `setViewPoint` function will flip the normals of the whole point cloud (rather than just an individual point) as long as it is called before the `compute` function.

For example, in this image the cloud on the left was computed before calling `setViewPoint`, and the cloud on the right was computed afterwards.

[image: normals_orientation_vs_not]

(You might need to open that image in a new tab to get the larger version so you can see the normal directions more clearly)